# How to ignore testcode for code coverage using cabal and hpc?

Tags: haskell, code-coverage, cabal

When using `cabal install --enable-tests --enable-library-coverage` to generate code coverage reports it will also generate code coverage reports for the testcode. Is there an option for cabal to let hpc ignore testcode?

Comment: As an alternative this might be interesting: https://github.com/guillaume-nargeot/codecov-haskell

Answer (score 1):

I'd be pleasantly surprised if cabal yet has an option for this. Getting HPC to ignore things is (or perhaps used to be) moderately complicated as this example shows: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_program_coverage#Example